# How to populate values in dropdowns using angularJS?

Tags: angularjs

How to populate dropdowns using angularJS?

I have succesfully setup the option in both dropdowns.

In my dropdown one is dependent to another ie Parent have correponding child

Suppose in my database I stored Parent name is London and Child name is London State2,

In my html page when i click an edit this content, i need to populate the entire data in my drop box with select this particular parent name as "London" and childname as "London State2"

The only thing when an editing a content that content will select in drobdown menu..

ie. I want to select Parent name as London and Child name is London State2 defaultly when in open this page

My problem when i open this page it will default as Parent name is --Select-- and Child name is --Select--

This is my script.js

script.js

```
var app=angular.module('TestApp', ['angular.filter','ui.router']);

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
    .state('category',
    {
    views : {  
        "body" :
    {
        url : '/category',
        templateUrl : 'category.html',
        controller : 'TestController'
    }
    }  

    })

    .state('category.subcategory',
    {
    url : '/subcategory',
    views : {                             
    "subbody@category" :
    {
    templateUrl : 'sample.html',
    controller : 'SampleController'             
    }
    }
    })
});

app.controller('MainController', MainController);

function MainController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is MainController")

    $scope.getCategory=function()
    {
    $state.go('category');
    }


}

app.controller('TestController', TestController);

//TestController.$inject['dataservice'];

function TestController($scope, $state){


    $scope.data=[
     {
      "parentName": "India",
      "childName": "India State1"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "USA",
      "childName": "USA State1"        
     },
     {
      "parentName": "London",
      "childName": "London State1"         
     },

     {
      "parentName": "India",
      "childName": "India State2"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "USA",
      "childName": "USA State2"        
     },
     {
      "parentName": "USA",
      "childName": "USA State3"         
     },
     {
      "parentName": "London",
      "childName": "London State2"         
     }
    ];

    $scope.selectedParent="London";
    $scope.selectedChild="London State2";

    function onParentChange(parent){
      if(!parent){
    $scope.child = undefined;
      }
    }


    $scope.getValue=function()
    {
    alert("Call to Sample Controller")

    var currentState = $state.current.name;
    var targetState = 'category.subcategory';

    if(currentState === targetState)
      $state.go($state.current, {}, {reload: true});
    else
    $state.go(targetState);
    $state.go(".subcategory");

    //$state.go('category.subcategory');
    }
}


app.controller('SampleController', SampleController);

function SampleController($scope,$state)
{
    alert("This is SampleController")

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="TestApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-route.min.js"></script>
          <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.8/angular-filter.js"></script>
          <script src="angular-ui-router.js"></script>     
        <script src="script.js"></script>
        <script src="angular-filter.js"></script>
  </head>

    <body ng-controller="MainController">
        <a href="#" ng-click="getCategory()">Click to Category</a>
        <div ui-view="body"></div>   
    </body>
</html>
```

category.html

```
  <div>   
    <hr>

    <div class="col-md-3">
      <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Parent</b></label>
      <select ng-model="selectedParent"
        ng-init="selectedParent = null"
        ng-change="onParentChange(selectedParent)"
        class="form-control" id="data">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        <option ng-repeat="(key,value) in data | orderBy:'parentName'| groupBy:'parentName'">{{key}}</option>          
      </select>
    </div>             
      </form> 
    </div>     
    <div class="col-md-3">     
      <form>   
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleSelect1"><b>Child Names</b></label>
      <select class="form-control" id="childnames" ng-model="child"
        ng-disabled="!selectedParent"
        ng-options="data.childName for data in data| filter: {parentName:selectedParent} | removeWith:{childName : 'Infant Food'}" ng-change="getValue()">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
      </select>
    </div>         

      </form>    
  </div>
    <div ui-view="subbody"></div>
  </div>
```

sample.html

```
<div>
    Sample Controller
</div>
```

Comment: Why have you added ng-init="selectedParent = null" if you what a default initial value as London

Answer (score 0):

From your Example you want London should be default value in your drop down.. you can achieve this by like this instead of ng-init,

```
$scope.selectedParent = 'London'
$scope.selectedParent = $scope.data[2]['parentName'] // it will show london according to your eg data file.

//for child,
$scope.child = 'London State1'
$scope.child = $scope.data[2]['childName']
```

This will update automatically when you selected values from dropdown in front end..

Comment: the thing is that in I stored student profile details in my database it include Countryname as London and statename as London State2.The problem is when i updating the corresponding student i want to display dropdown ie(Countryname and statename) as what he stored in the database.And one more thing these statename is dependent t countryname too

Comment: yes same, you can update above scope under where the http request happens.. like if one student update, u have some http request for that right. at the end of success update above scope from returning json obejct, eg: }).success(response)  { $scope.child = response[index]['parentName'] } like this it will update your drop down . if its not what you want.. tell me clearly will explain .